# How do store a value throughout an asp.net mvc (razor 3) application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-state

For example if a user is loggged in, what would be the best approach for storing the userID and/or his/her roles/groups? The obvious approaches are cookies and session? What other options?

Comment: If you want to store the values per user, I think those are the best options

Comment: I don't completely follow, can you give me an example?

Comment: I added more detail in an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, using Forms Authentication you can put user id and the roles in the Formst Auth Ticket.

Here'a an example of how I did it:

```
    public static HttpCookie CreateCookie(IUserIdValue userId, string name, IEnumerable<int> group, bool isPersistent = false)
    {
        var user = new AuthenticationTicketData() { Groups = @group, UserId = userId };
        var ft = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, name, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout),
                                               isPersistent, user.Pack());
        var ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName)
                     {
                         Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ft),
                         Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
                         Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
                     };
        if (isPersistent)
        {
            ck.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout);
        }
        return ck;
    }


 public static string Pack(this AuthenticationTicketData data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        return String.Format("{0};{1}",PackUserId(data.UserId),string.Join(",",data.Groups));
    }

    static string PackUserId(IUserIdValue uid)
    {
        if (uid == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("uid");
        var tpn = uid.GetType().GetFullTypeName();
        return String.Format("{0}|{1}",tpn,uid.ToString());
    }

 public static HttpCookie SetAuthCookie(this HttpResponse response,IUserIdValue userId, string name, IEnumerable<int> group, bool isPersistent = false)
    {
        var ck = CreateCookie(userId, name, group, isPersistent);
        response.AppendCookie(ck);
        return ck;
    }
```

Another alternative is to keep the user session (no relation to Session) in the database, something like a table(guid,username,userid,roles,expireAt). But this approach is more suitable if you want to keep track of when a user logins/logout or if you're using your own authentication (not Forms auth).

Comment: Thank you for the example and explaination!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the values per user, I session is the best option. Session is created on a per-user/browser basis. Each user has his/her own session object, so in this way you can keep the user roles information accross the application until the session ending.

I definitely won't recommend storing user security info in a cookie, because that will cause a big security hole in your application.